# Displaying an image outside of its container

Tags: image, html, header, containers

After searching this site, and Google, I have given up on figuring out this seemingly simple task alone. There's got to be something that I am missing, but I just can't get it. I've been using the dev tools in Chrome, and Firefox (to include the use of Firebug) without any luck.

The most relevant topic I've found is here: [Position an image outside of its container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885835/position-an-image-outside-of-its-container)

Using the suggestions from the above article yielded no results as well. Here is my site: http://www.enoctis.net/

The image in question is part of the header, which will be immediately obvious. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is not a very direct answer to your question, but could you simply change the width of the "logo_container" div from its current width of 430px to a width of 526px (which is the width of the logo image)? From my tests, this does not seem to affect the layout of the page.

Comment: With the current top (right) navigation, that wouldn't be an issue, but when I later add more items to the nav menu, then they will be truncated. Thanks for your reply, though.